# Wordpress and permalinks for separate Countries (with Geotargeting)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I am developing a multilingual website in Wordpress with 4 different languages (English, Italian, Russian and Spanish). I have used both WPML and qTranslate in the past and but I am trying to figure out something slightly more particular.
I would like to bea able to subdividide the sites permalink by COUNTRY.

For example, if I create a page with slug "about" (in English, and for example, slug "chi-siamo" in Italian -> easily done in WPML)

I would like it to be accessible from

- www.domain.com/us/about -> UNITED STATES, page served in English
- www.domain.com/uk/about -> UNITED KINGDOM, page served in English
- www.domain.com/it/chi-siamo -> ITALY, page served in Italian

I have already found a geotargeting function, what I am looking for is how to setup permalinks/htaccess/taxonomies for this to work...

**UPDATE:**
forgot to mention, the list of countries is quite big (around 100) and can be variable

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, why don't you try making 3 different pages with your links, all in different/same languages?

Comment: the real problem is I will have 100 different countries :( can't really make 100 different pages for every page/post/custom type

Comment: You can write a plugin/htaccess/permalink etc. to redirect to one page.

Comment: well, yes... that's what I'm planning on doing. Any ideas on how to implement that?

Comment: In such cases (long but easy cases), I write an app which does write that for me, changing a few places in it. In your case a app that would automatically translate the word ("about") to a language and add it to a line and save it might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a c# app that automatically creats a htaccess file, here is an example

```
void translateandmake()
    {
        List<string> countrycodes = new List<string>(); //Your country code list
        countrycodes.Add("tr");
        countrycodes.Add("en");
        YandexTranslate.YandexTranslator trnslate = new YandexTranslate.YandexTranslator(); //Made with https://www.nuget.org/packages/YandexTranslate.dll/

        string output = "";
        foreach (string countrycode in countrycodes)
        {
            output += "Redirect http://example.com/" + countrycode + @"/" + trnslate.translate("about", "apikey-here-get-from-http://api.yandex.com/key/form.xml?service=trnsl", countrycode) + " /About.html" + Environment.NewLine;
            //source http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F
        }
        MessageBox.Show(output);
    }
```

ps. I'm not great at making htaccess files, so please edit the htaccess part (Redirect etc.)

pps. here is an example output:

Redirect http://example.com/tr/hakkında /About.html

Redirect http://example.com/en/about /About.html

Comment: Hmmm... Don't really see how that would help in Wordpress in a LAMP setup :(